# Can't build the STM32 microcontroller project in System Workbench

Tags: c, system, stm32, workbench, nucleo

Installed System Workbench IDE, started new project. Downloading firmware for my board F103RB didn't work - only downloads first ~200kb of a zip file and then stops, so i had to find it manually (it had the same name so should be correct) and extract in `C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Ac6\SW4STM32\firmwares`. After doing this, System Workbench found the firmware and didn't prompt to download it; project is created. Then I downloaded [toolchain](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download) and after installation I checked the checkbox to add it to Path. Then when building the project these this error remains and I'm stuck here:

[image: Problems tab ("sluchawki" is a project name)]

and Console tab outputs this:

```
10:27:06 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project sluchawki ****
make all 
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, echo "Building file: ../startup/startup_stm32f10x_md.S", ...) failed.
make (e=2): Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku. [Can't find specified file.]

make: *** [startup/startup_stm32f10x_md.o] Error 2

10:27:07 Build Finished (took 1s.403ms)
```

Comment: SW4STM32 has its own toolchain which comes with the installer.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your project directory tree, open the startup directory. Generally Eclipse does not recognise `.S` (upper case S) just `.s` as assembler file.

Comment: I have just created a project with SW4STM with an STM32F103RB Nucelo and works fine. Also it does not have `/startup/startup_stm32f10x_md.S` file. Just a `/startup/startup_stm32f103xb.s`. Change that upper case S to a lower case at the first place. Here is an [STM32 documentation link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/stm32/7617/getting-started-with-stm32/25059/first-time-setup-with-blink-led-example#t=201611130959466733217), with step by step project creation guide in SW4STM32. Try it with F103RB.

Comment: 1. I had these problems before: "arm-none-eabi-g++" not found in PATH and "arm-none-eabi-gcc" not found in PATH. Installing toolchain fixed it.

2. Project directory tree: http://i.imgur.com/BysZ5Zc.png

3. Changing S to lower case gives the same error.

Comment: 3. Changing filename to startup_stm32f103xb.s shows different error in Problems tab: "make: *** No rule to make target `startup/startup_stm32f10x_md.o', needed by `sluchawki.elf'.  Stop." and in Console tab: 
"12:19:10 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project sluchawki ****
make all 
make: *** No rule to make target `startup/startup_stm32f10x_md.o', needed by `sluchawki.elf'.  Stop.

12:19:10 Build Finished (took 175ms)"

Comment: You do not have to change the name, the point was that in my case the project looks different.

Comment: But I have F103RB too, so i thought it maybe should be named startup_stm32f103xb.s.